# Javers.commit() not working MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, javers

I am getting below error: and I am working with Spring Boot AOP Javers.
Javers.commit() works fine in another class but in aspect class it gave me below error.
i don't know if there is a special way to work with AOP and Javers at the same time.

my code is here : https://github.com/mohamedBenali100/JaversAOPIssue

```
org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'class java.lang.Long' is mapped to PrimitiveType, expected ManagedType
    at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapper.getJaversManagedType(TypeMapper.java:194) ~[javers-core-5.9.0.jar:na]
```

**My Aspect Class**

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.javers.core.Javers;
import org.javers.core.JaversBuilder;
import org.javers.repository.jql.QueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ContactAspect {

    Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().registerValueObject(Contact.class).build();


    @Autowired
    ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* ma.dxc.ContactServiceImpl.save(..))")
    public void mySavePointcut(){ }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* ma.dxc.ContactServiceImpl.update(..)) && args(id,contact,..)")
    public void myUpdatePointcut(Long id, Contact contact){ }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "mySavePointcut()",returning= "result")
    public void logAfterReturningUsers(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) throws Throwable{
        Contact contact = (Contact) result;
        System.out.println("contact added : "+contact.toString());
    }

    @Around("myUpdatePointcut(id,contact)")
    public Object applicationLogger (ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Long id, Contact contact) throws Throwable {


        Contact contactAudited = contactRepository.getOne(id);      
        javers.commit("hamada",contactAudited);

        Object object = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

        contactAudited = contactRepository.getOne(id);
        javers.commit("hamada",contactAudited);
        String changes = javers.findChanges( QueryBuilder.byInstance(contactAudited).build()).toString();

        System.out.println("contact updated by this changes : "+changes);

        return object;
    }
}
```

**My Service Class**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactrepository ;


    public List<Contact> findAll() {
         return contactrepository.findAll();
    }


    public Contact save(@Valid Contact contact) {
        return contactrepository.save(contact) ;
    }

    public Contact findOne(long id) {
        return contactrepository.getOne(id);
    }
    @Transactional
    public Contact update(@Valid Long id, Contact contact) {
        contact.setId(id);
        return contactrepository.saveAndFlush(contact);
    }}
```

**My Contact Class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;


@Entity
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id ;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String Fname;

    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String Lname;

    public Contact() {
        super();
    }

    public Contact(@NotNull @Size String fname, @NotNull @Size String lname) {
        super();
        Fname = fname;
        Lname = lname;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return Fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        Fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return Lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        Lname = lname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact [Fname=" + Fname + ", Lname=" + Lname + "]";
    }
}
```

**my repository class**

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends JpaRepository<Contact, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Contact> {

}
```

** my Main Class **

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContactApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ContactServiceImpl contactServiceImpl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContactApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Contact contact = new Contact("tom","hunx");
        contactServiceImpl.save(contact);
        contact.setLname("cruise");
        contactServiceImpl.update(Long.valueOf(1), contact);
    }}
```

Comment: hi, try to push a runnable test case here https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases

Comment: hi @BartekWalacik i'm new in programing and i need a document showing how to make runnable test like those tests in your link. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Hello again. Why did you delete the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61855519/1082681) and create it again for the very same problem? Is this always what you do when other people criticise lack of detail or other things in comments? I know you are new here and do not want to offend you in any way, but please note that I believe this is neither particularly polite nor efficient.

Comment: Hi @kriegaex, your last message was very touching (you were right and I believe that I was too hasty) so i wanted to do it again but do it right This time.

Comment: This question is much better indeed, but still not an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. I cannot copy and run it. There are missing dependency classes (e.g. `PermissionService`, `PermissionRepository`, `AuditRepository`), missing configuration, missing packages names and imports. I know you are a beginner, but this is a complex question and the best way to analyse this is to see a full sample project, ideally incl. Maven or Gradle build configuration, uploaded to GitHub. Then everyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'll try to do that now

Comment: i puched my code here https://github.com/mohamedBenali100/JaversAOPIssue

Comment: The application does not start because I have no local MySQL server and I do not know what kind of tables I need to create there. Or would they be created automatically by the Spring Boot application if I set up an empty MySQL? Sorry, but I am not an application framework guy and don't know much about them. It would have been better if you modified your application to just create an in-memory DB like H2 during start-up, so the application can be used in order to reproduce the actual problem. Maybe you can do that for me. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, after installing MySQL 8 locally, I know the result: The DB is not created automatically. `SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'dbcontacts'` So I would need SQL scripts for that which I can execute on the client console.

Comment: You need just to create the DB named **dbcontacts** and the rest will be done by spring-boot. Script to create DB is : create database dbcontacts;

Comment: @kriegaex thank you for your time i learned a lot from this experience with you. Your instructions helped me a lot. thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my code or i shuld say a friend of mine who helped me to find it. So in my case there is 4 mistakes i did :

1_ in pom file i used : javers-core but i shuld use javers-spring as dependency

2_ In my service class i used : javax.transaction.Transactional but i shuld use org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
and i shuld add .orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new) to my functions to evoid exception when your object is not there.

3_ I had to add a configuration calss named JaversConfig with Bean javers.

4_ In my Aspect class i needed to use DI for javers and needed to use service instead of repository for searching for an object.

I don't know if i explainted that well but you will find my working code in this link:
https://github.com/mohamedBenali100/JaversAOPIssue